# Will I lose my MozRank / MozTrust / Page Authority if I upgrade my site?

Tags: seo, ranking

I've created a new layout for my site, which involves completely changing the CSS and page HTML, but keeping the same text and the same pages (I didn't delete any file).

Will I lose my MozRank / MozTrust / Page Authorityif I upload this new version? How exactly are these factors generated?

Comment: All three metrics are useless and worthless

Comment: Mozwhat? MOZRank and MOZTrust are an attempt to revitalize a dead directory system that lost relevance a long time ago. It's along the same lines of the Majestic search engine that's trying to rebrand as a SEO statistics service (Marketing Search Engine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are Moz Metrics based on your back links linking back to you. So if you change something on page it will not change those score directly. Those Metrics are developed my moz.com so be aware they are not affiliated with Google as organization by any way.

## MozRank

represents a link popularity score. It reflects the importance of any given web page on the Internet. Pages earn MozRank by the number and quality of other pages that link to them. The higher the quality of the incoming links, the higher the MozRank.

## MozTrust

is Moz's global link trust score. It is similar to MozRank, but rather than measuring link popularity, it measures link trust. Receiving links from sources with inherent trust—such as the homepages of major university websites or certain government web pages—is a strong trust endorsement.

## Page Authority

is a score (on a 100-point scale) developed by Moz that predicts how well a specific page will rank on search engines. It is based off data from the Mozscape web index and includes link counts, MozRank, MozTrust, and dozens of other factors. It uses a machine learning model to predictively find an algorithm that best correlates with rankings across the thousands of search results that we predict against.

Here what google thinks about SEO:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291?hl=en